# @Consumes annotation throwing Exception, How to Handle

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, annotations

My service accepts a Json and Consumes it for me and maps it to my DTOs.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/service")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myService(Request requestBody) {
     //Stuff
}
```

However, there are certain fields in my DTOs that will throw a JsonMapperException exception if that particular element is null.

Since this happens before I actually enter the service, how can I gracefully handle this exception and return a Json with a custom error code and message?

And furthermore, how do I mark an element as "Optional" so the mapper will just ignore it if it is null or missing, but serialize it if it is non-empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question.

The reason this was throwing an exception was because I was attempting to do logic in my DTO. That logic would fail if the incoming element was NULL. There was no easy way around this.

However, best practices calls for doing as little logic in DTOs as possible. So I simply moved the logic to the main method of the service and did my calculations there.

Problem solved.